# CakePHP email with CSS

Tags: php, css, email, cakephp

I am unable to get the css in email, Following is the CakePHP email function:

```
function _sendMailUser($mailTo = array(), $mailFrom = array(), $repTo = array(), $mailSubject = null, $mailTemplate = null) {
    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $email -> from($mailFrom);
    $email -> bcc($mailTo);
    $email -> replyTo($repTo);
    $email -> subject($mailSubject);
    $email -> template($mailTemplate);
    $email -> emailFormat('html');

    return $email -> send();

}
```

Email Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo HTTP_ROOT; ?>css/style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">

    <center>
        <?php echo $this -> fetch('content'); ?>
    </center>

</body>
```

Everything works fine except the CSS. I even tried to include `<style>....</style>` in the head section but didn't work.

Comment: Show your css code. And dont link css styles on emails. And which email service provider did you send email?

Comment: Not getting css, tried multiple email providers Gmail, Yahoo etc...

Comment: I use [this](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Lib/InlineCssLib.php) to convert inline style and CSS into "inline CSS" which is the best working CSS approach. This can happen via helper callback for example right before actually passing it to the Transport class.

Comment: You should use inline styles. Not every mail client supports the style tags in the header and/or body.

Comment: put there full URI to your css file :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write css inline in template:

```
 <h2 style="color:#818381">Here are the latest stories everyone's talking about...</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function _sendNewUserMail($emaildetail = null)
    {
        $this->Email->to = $emaildetail['to'];
        $this->Email->bcc = array('er.ahmad.hassan@gmail.com');
        //$this->Email->bcc = '';
        $this->Email->subject = $emaildetail['subject'];
        $this->Email->replyTo = 'XXX@gmail.com';
        $this->Email->from = 'XYZ@apyl.com';
        $this->Email->template = $emaildetail['messagebody'];
        $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
        $this->Email->__header[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
        $this->Email->smtpOptions = array('port' => '25', 'timeout' => '30', 'host' =>     "000.0.000.000",
        'username' => "xyz@example.com", 'password' => 'XXX', 'client' =>    'smtp_helo_hostname');
        $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
        $this->set('emaildetail', $emaildetail);
        $this->Email->send();
        $this->set('smtp-errors', $this->Email->smtpError);
        return true;
}
```

[Mail Template Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadhasankhan/9s8JA/)

Answer (score 0):

brother of code

My name is john, I recommended use https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles.

It's one component for html and css separated file insert css into style balise inline for all element compose html.

Warning, I use in my project and frequent problem when use with multiple htmls files.

I created one patch for problem, contact me for retreive patch.

Comment: "Brother of code" - It looks like a sect. Where do I sign? Also worth reading [The Ultimate Guide to CSS in mails](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a css file, it should be in `/app/webroot/css` with the extension style.css and then you should include the following line in your template file:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css(array('style')); ?>
```

for the view file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <?php echo $this->Html->css(array('style')); ?>
    </head>
    <body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">

        <center>
            <?php echo $this -> fetch('content'); ?>
        </center>

    </body>
```